# Setting focus inside textarea doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group" id="checkDiv_0">
    <div class="col-md-2 control-label">
        @Translations.ReportCopy
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <textarea id="textarea_0" name="Copies" class="form-control textarea-resize"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="checkDiv_1">
    <div class="col-md-2 control-label">
        @Translations.ReportCopy
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <textarea id="textarea_1" name="Copies" class="form-control textarea-resize"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to set focus on textare with the id `textarea_1`. Without the focus the user must left-click insisde the textarea and than can start writting inside it.

I tried with `$('#textarea_1').focus()`, but without success.

**SOLUTION:**
 I solved the problem this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal',
    function () {
        var element = document.getElementById("textarea_0");
        element.focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: Where/how/when are you calling `$('#textarea_1').focus()` ? You are probably calling it to early. Haven't you read the jQuery tutorial? https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#launching-code-on-document-ready

Comment: Do you want it to have focus when the document loads?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your jQuery code inside the `.ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textarea_1").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two examples without jQuery:

```
window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('textarea_1').focus(); };
```

or

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { document.getElementById('textarea_1').focus(); }, false);
```

The second one allows you to assign multiple `'onload'` events to single DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need javascript for this question, since you can just do:

```
<textarea id="textarea_1" name="Copies" class="form-control textarea-resize" autofocus></textarea>
```

The autofocus attribute focuses the text area as default on the DOM.

You can use this page as reference: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_autofocus.asp

Answer (score -1):

The code necessary really depends on when you need to give it focus. If you need to give it focus when the page loads, you should do what @David Li suggested.

Otherwise, you can do something like this.

```js
document.getElementById('focusButton').onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById('textarea_1').focus();
};
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group" id="checkDiv_0">
            <div class="col-md-2 control-label">
                @Translations.ReportCopy
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <textarea id="textarea_0" name="Copies" class="form-control textarea-resize"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group" id="checkDiv_1">
            <div class="col-md-2 control-label">
                @Translations.ReportCopy
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <textarea id="textarea_1" name="Copies" class="form-control textarea-resize"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <input type="button" id="focusButton" value="give element focus">
```

Comment: *"You must wait for the browser to finish rendering."* True, but there are better ways than using an arbitrary timeout. There are listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196

Comment: You are correct. I made the jsfiddle in firefox. I tested it now in opera and it worked without all the extra code. Firefox is hit or miss.